# How to Use 2 Conditional On Angular Selector

Tags: angular

I have a multiple input component with selector like this:

```html
<app-input type="currency" formControlName="currency"></app-input>

<app-input type="date" formControlName="dateOfBirth"></app-input>
```

So, from that component, I have a selector like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input[type=currency]',
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input[type=date]',
})
```

Now, i want to add multiple `currency` component. One for default currency component and the second one for currency with dynamic currency symbols.

So, i want to make it different with options. When selector have an options, show currency with dynamic symbols, else or default, show default currency without symbols.

I've been trying to using this selector below, but it's not working.

For default currency:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input:not([options])[type=currency]',
})
```

For dynamic symbol currency:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input[options][type=currency]',
})
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

#### BEST WAY:

You should just use a single component and insert the conditionals inside that component to perform this dynamic behaviour based on the config from `@Input` instead going for multiple components, if its unavoidable then check the below approach

---

#### Option 2

> The reason options does not work is because, angular appends extra values to the attribute, if you want you original solution to work, you can change it to

For default currency:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input:not([ng-reflect-options])[type=currency]',
})
```

For dynamic symbol currency:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input[ng-reflect-options][type=currency]',
})
```

---

#### Option 3

You can just add data attributes to differentiate the selector like so

Without Symbols:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input[type=currency]',
})
```

With Symbols:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input[type=currency][data-symbols]',
})
```

html

```
with symbols: <app-input type="currency" formControlName="currency" data-symbols></app-input>
without symbols: <app-input type="currency" formControlName="currency"></app-input>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, when i trying your selector and replace `ng-reflect-options` with `options`, now it working fine. I don't know why it's error before. But thank you for your help. It's really2 helpfull